# magnolia authentication

Tags: java, magnolia

this my first post here .. please help me i'm out of solutions

my problem is that i made a dialog in magnolia and the user should enter the DMS link of his xsl file 
which i want to read

and i used the savehandler and extend the class needed

when i start to read the uploaded file i got this error

```
" HTTP response code: 401 for URL: "
```

note : i tried to read the same file from the path of my computer and everything went right

any help ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the user doesn't use have write permissions on the `dms` workspace ?

Comment: i'm logging as a superuser and even though i tried and give the anonymous full control but still the same problem

Comment: hmm that's odd. Saw your post on the magnolia forum now, probably a better chance of having an answer there, but it might be a good idea to give some more details (such as the fact that you're logged in as superuser;))